# Nginx: serving static files by URL path

Tags: nginx, webserver, static-files, serving

Is there any way of serving static files by only some URL path? For example, next URL pattern `http://host/static/*.png` has `/static/` substring (path), and Nginx will serve any statics from there.

In the web server documentation I found an example:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js)$ { ...
```

and defined my Nginx config like that:

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /apib {
         #some proxy_pass
    }

    location /apim {
         #some proxy_pass
    }

    location /api {
         #some proxy_pass
    }
```

I try to add additional `location` for `*/static/*.*` with root dir `/var/www/some_statics`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
location ~* ^/static/.+\.(png|whatever-else)$ {
    alias /var/www/some_static;
    expires 24h;
}
location / {
    # regular rules
}
```

Hand written, may contain mistakes.

If you want to extend the rules to match `anything/something/static/*.png` just remove the `^` in the patten.

Comment: Nginx send index page (root) from server section in config.

Comment: @akrisanov That's right. They are inherited from upper level config unless specified by `root` or `alias` inside the block.

Comment: http://d.pr/i/ViNT I mean, your solution doesn't work. My full config now: https://gist.github.com/akrisanov/8413535

Comment: Did you reload the configuration / restart the nginx? and you may also try `location /static/ { alias /var/www/some_static; }` or read [this](/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias)

Answer (score 0):

```js
location ^~ /static/ {
    alias /var/www/some_static;
}
```